# Каким образом ОС отслеживает допустимость обращений по тому или иному адресу?

Tags: windows, x86, virtual, memory-management

Интересует следующий момент. Как осуществляется контроль доступа по тому или иному адресу с точки зрения обработки процессом кода процесса. Насколько я понял, есть два способа: задание через атрибуты сегмента (чтение, запись, исполнение), либо через атрибуты PDE/PTE (чтение, запись). Но как следует из многочисленных источников, эти механизмы в ОС Windows почти не задействованы. Там ключевую роль играет менеджер памяти, задающий регионы, назначающий им атрибуты (PAGE_READWRITE, PAGE_READONLY, PAGE_EXECUTE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, PAGE_NOACCESS, PAGE_GUARD: их гораздо больше, чем можно было бы задать для сегмента памяти) и контролирующий доступ к этим регионам. Непонятно, на каком этапе может включаться в работу этот менеджер памяти? Поскольку процессор может встретить инструкцию: записать такие данные по такому адресу (даже, если этот адрес относится к региону, выделенному менеджером памяти с атрибутом, например, PAGE_READONLY) и ничего не мешает ему это выполнить. Таким образом, менеджер памяти остается в стороне не участвует в процессе...

Comment: Тоненбаум "Операционные системы". Там хорошо описаны механизмы защиты памяти.

Answer (score 1):

Этот механизм действует на уровне процессора. Процесс работает с линейным адресом, процессор же через таблицу страниц преобразует его в физический, одновременно проверяя разрешения. Если разрешения страницы и команды не совпали, то вызывается специальная функция ОС, которая уже решает что делать.

Например, если страница помечена как ReadOnly, это может быть не только нарушением доступа, но и частью механизма Copy-On-Write, и тогда ОС сделает копию страницы с нужными атрибутами, подправит таблицу адресов так, чтобы тот же линейный адрес преобразовывался в новый физический и вернет управление на команду, вызвавшую ошибку.

**UPD** про атрибуты, и почему у аллокатора их больше чем у сегмента.

Атрибуты сегмента хранятся в регистрах процессора.

Атрибуты страницы памяти (для x86 это кусок в 4096 байт) хранятся в специальной структуре - таблице страниц. Менеджер памяти Windows работает со страницами и любой выделяемых им регион всегда выровнен по границам страниц памяти. Аллокатор ОС задает атрибуты страниц, а процессор их проверяет при каждом доступе к памяти из пользовательского режима.

**UPD2**
Как уточнил Fat-Zer, атрибуты менеджера памяти и атрибуты страницы - не одно и то же. Разные атрибуты менеджера памяти могут преобразовываться в одинаковые атрибуты страниц, т.к. первые - это логический смысл набора атрибутов, а вторые - как их реализовывать физически.

Comment: Из ответа не совсем понятно, как так получается, что "их (атрибутов в Windows) гораздо больше, чем можно было бы задать для сегмента памяти"

Comment: поправлю малость: запись в страницу с `PAGE_READONLY` — это только `Access Violation` т.к. это чисто софтверный логический флаг и он ни как не может быть частью реализации CoW'а, а вот для страницы с установленным битом `R/W`=`0` в PTE эти рассуждения как раз верны.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо за уточнение. Подзабыл малость.

Comment: Атрибуты сегмента НЕ хранятся в регистрах. Вернее все немного сложнее. Они НЕ хранятся в доступных регистрах, там только селектор сегмента. Атрибуты лежат в дескрипторе сегмента, в таблице сегментов (глобальной или локальной). Но для быстродействия атрибуты как сегментов так и страниц кешируются в теневой части регистров

Answer (score 0):

> Поскольку процессор может встретить инструкцию: записать такие данные
>   по такому адресу (даже, если этот адрес относится к региону,
>   выделенному менеджером памяти с атрибутом, например, PAGE_READONLY) и
>   ничего не мешает ему это выполнить. Таким образом, менеджер памяти
>   остается в стороне не участвует в процессе...

На том уровне приоритета, на котором работает пользовательская программа, процессор не может получить доступ к регистрам MMU. Стало быть при попытке записать в страницу памяти, помеченную как PAGE_READONLY возникнет системное прерывание.

Недавно обсуждали эту и смежные темы. Вот ссылка:

[Как исполняется машинный код и как система ограничивает его права?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853040/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0/853267#853267)

Answer (score 0):

> Как осуществляется контроль доступа по тому или иному адресу с точки зрения обработки процессором кода процесса.

Основной механизм контроля доступа — на основе установки битов защиты страниц в PTE (*Page Table Entry*). Возможности защиты памяти на уровне сегментов/селекторов практически нигде не используются и практически все 32/64-битные ОС эмулируют простую плоскую модель памяти как для процессов так и для ядра загружая в селекторные регистры заглушки, которые просто адресуют всю доступную память.

Основные биты PTE, которые используются менеджером памяти для контроля доступа:

```
 Смещение 
 |  Мнемоника (расшифровка)
 |  |                     Описание
 |  |                     |
 0  P   (Present)         Присутствует ли страница в памяти
 1  R/W (Read/Wright)     Если =0, то страница защищена от записи
 2  U/S (User/Supervisor) Выставляется в =0 для защиты памяти ядра*
...
# Также в режиме PAE или amd64, когда используются 64-х битные PTE есть ещё один бит:
63  NX  (No eXecute)      Если =1, то загрузка инструкций из страницы запрещена**
```

<sup>* далее рассматривается только управление памяти пользовательскими процессами, поэтому подразумевается, что он `=1`, здесь бит `U/S` упомянут только ради справки

** на intel'овских процессорах он появился только с приходом i686 (Pentium4+); весёлые intel'овские инженеры называют этот бит `XD`</sup>

Соответственно защита от исполнения данных будет работать только на amd64 или в PAE-режиме.

> Непонятно, на каком этапе может включаться в работу этот менеджер памяти?

Менеджер памяти обычно вступает в игру в двух случаях:

1. При запросе на выделения/освобождения памяти. При выделении он устанавливает для каждой страницы региона соответствующие биты. При освобождении, соответственно, помечает все страницы региона в PTE как отсутствующие.
2. При страничном прерывании. При отсутствии специфических условий он посылает исключение `Access Violation`, но также программно реализует особое поведение, если страница вытеснена в файл подкачки, а также логику работы, если для региона установлены флаги `PAGE_GUARD`, `PAGE_WRITECOPY` или что-то ещё необычное.

При этом менеджер памяти оперирует *регионами* (сознательно избегаю здесь термина *сегмент*), а не отдельными страницами. И хранит соответствующие настройки для них

#### Примеры соответствия битов защиты страниц при выставлении флагов регионов

```
Флаг                    P   R/W NX
PAGE_NOACCESS           0   ?   ?
PAGE_READONLY           1   0   1
PAGE_READWRITE          1   1   1
PAGE_EXECUTE            1   0   0
PAGE_EXECUTE_READ       1   0   0
PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE  1   1   0

PAGE_GUARD              0   ?   ?
PAGE_WRITECOPY          1   0   ?
```

#### Немного описания логики работы

Как видно из таблицы с точки зрения процессора страницы регионов с `PAGE_NOACCESS`, `PAGE_GUARD` (а также страницы вытесненные в файл подкачки). Разное поведение обеспечивается здесь менеджером памяти при страничном прерывании, для PAGE_NOACCESS посылается исключение `Access Violation`, для вытесненной страницы происходит её загрузка, а для `PAGE_GUARD` какая-то своя логика.

Аналогично страницы с `PAGE_WRITECOPY | PAGE_READWRITE` и `PAGE_READONLY`: первые при страничном прерывании вызывают копирование страницы, а вторые — `Access Violation`.

Также неразличимы `PAGE_EXECUTE` и `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ`. Здесь сложнее сказать, зачем их разделили. Возможно, прицел был на какую-то сферическую архитектуру в вакууме, а возможно, есть какие-то внутренние эвристики, которые ведут себя для них по-разному. В любом случае `PAGE_EXECUTE` не защищает от чтения из страницы.

> Поскольку процессор может встретить инструкцию: записать такие данные по такому адресу (даже, если этот адрес относится к региону, выделенному менеджером памяти с атрибутом, например, PAGE_READONLY) и ничего не мешает ему это выполнить. Таким образом, менеджер памяти остается в стороне не участвует в процессе...

Как уже говорил выше, вся обработка идёт через страничное прерывание: если страница, в которую производится запись относится к региону `PAGE_READONLY`, то в PTE для неё установлен бит `R/W`=0. Соответственно при его обработке как раз управление и передаётся менеджеру памяти.

#### Дисклеймер

Всё вышеописанное стоит снабдить здоровой порцией оборотов «скорее всего» и «наверняка» т.к., во-первых,  Windows — это ОС с закрытым исходным кодом и нет гарантий, что она на самом деле работает так как описано в документации и книжках про неё, а, во-вторых, я не занимался глубоким анализом внутреннего устройства оной и большинство моих выводов основаны на здравом смысле и аналогии с другими ОС (чего уж там греха таить, в первую очередь —  Linux).

Comment: Интересно было бы уточнить, если это возможно. Где хранятся настройки для регионов памяти?

Comment: @Николай, не совсем понял вопрос... в какой-то структуре менеджера памяти (вероятно в списке), который является подсистемой ядра ОС.